# How to prevent system columns generated by default in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

Every time when I create a table in pgadmin 4. Systems columns(tableoid, oid, xmix,xmax, cmin,cmax) are generated by default. When i import a CSV file using pgadmin4 GUI it throws an error since I don't have those columns in CSV file. I have to manually unchoose or uncheck systems columns in columns option before importing.I was not facing this issue before.

Here is the create table command generated when i created using pg admin

```
CREATE TABLE public."LineChart1"
(
    "Date" date,
    "Price" money
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE public."LineChart1"
    OWNER to eerfrusycfampt;
```

Error Message

```
ERROR:  column "tableoid" of relation "LineChart1" does not exist
```

How to prevent system columns generated by default?

Thanks

Comment: You can't prevent that because those are system columns and required so that Postgres works properly. The `oid` column however should _not_ be created with any recent Postgres version unless you add `with oids` to the `create table` statement. The presence of those columns will **not** generate an error during import.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table in question and the "import" statement you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) [edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Those columns aren't generated. They are service columns. Postgresql COPY command, when copying CSVs, only works with columns explicitly declared in the table.

Comment: So what is the **exact** statement you use to import the CSV file?

Comment: I use pgadmin4 GUI